# Using a SHA512 hash to encrypt data

Tags: sha-512

How can I judge the level of security with the following algorithm:

I create a 64 byte hash using SHA512 via some input. I use this hash to iterate over the plaintext, byte by byte, and similarly iterate over the hash byte by byte XORing each byte of the plaintext with a respective byte from the hash like this (in C#):

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
  if (j == key.Length) j = 0;
  data[i] = (byte)(data[i] ^ key[j++]);

}
```

where key is a byte array containing the hash. Issues of how the code acquires the key aside, is this secure? (Apologies if I am not framing this with the proper terminology). I am not using a salt. The input which is used to create the hash can be of any length (up to being reasonable; i.e., not a huge block of text).

Comment: If the message is longer than 64 bytes, this turns into a variant of the vigenere cipher, with its known weakenesses. If you use the key more than once, it turns into a many-time-pad, which is also very weak.

Comment: Vigenere would imply that the keylength is unknown, which was for a long time the main problem, when frequency analysis could already be used to break Caesar.

Comment: Related questions: [\[key-reuse\] \[one-time-pad\]](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-reuse+one-time-pad)

Comment: @tylo It turned out there is a fairly simple statistical method to identify the key length used in a Vigenere cipher. So there is no practical difference between a Vigenere cipher with a known and an unknown key length.

Comment: There is evidence for frequency analysis in the 9th century by Al-kindi. Vigenere was broken in 1863. And that breakthrough was how to find out the key length. The rest was just using techniques, which were a millenium old already. That *was* the problem, even if it isn't any more today with our current knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

No it's not. It is really bad.

Basically, this is a stream cipher, where your keystream is $key | key| key|key....$. This is really bad, similar to the level of "using OTP twice". As If you take a block of size keylength, and XOR two such blocks, then you get the XOR of the plaintexts. Depending on the nature of the plaintext, this can be really easy to guess.

If you want an easy encryption scheme, like XOR the plaintext with a keystream, use a stream cipher or a block cipher in [OFB mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_Feedback_.28OFB.29). If you want a construction with SHA512, that is also possible, see e.g.

- [Is it feasible to build a stream cipher from a cryptographic hash function?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-it-feasible-to-build-a-stream-cipher-from-a-cryptographic-hash-function)
- [Can I use HMAC-SHA1 in counter mode to make a stream cipher?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/can-i-use-hmac-sha1-in-counter-mode-to-make-a-stream-cipher)

However, since hash functions have different security properties than stream ciphers, it might be better to use a construction which is actually intended to be used this way. In a similar context, Bruce Schneier wrote (about ciphers based on hash functions):

> While these constructions can be secure, they depend on the choice of the underlying one-way hash function. A good one-way hash function does not necessarily make a secure encryption algorithm. Cryptographic requirements are different. For example, linear cryptanalysis is not a viable attack against one-way hash functions, but works against encryption algorithms. A one-way hash function such as SHA could have linear characteristics which, while not affecting its security as a one-way hash function, could make it insecure in an encryption algorithm such as MDC. I know of no cryptanalytic analysis of particular one-way hash functions as block ciphers; wait for such analysis before you trust any of them.

Comment: I read the link "is it feasible..." and note this: If the attacker can guess some plaintext_n, he can derive pad_n from ciphertext_n and from this all the following pad_i - which means that he can read the rest of the message.  BUT I don't understand in the sense that 1) how would an attacker guess some plaintext_n? And even if he could guess plaintext_n (but also: How would he know he's right?) and could therefore derive key_n, how could knowing key_n help in figuring out any other key(n)? Apologies if I'm not making sense.

Comment: @Ron Natural language has enough redundancy that you get partial plaintext recovery if you use the same pad twice and nearly perfect recovery if you use it three times.

Comment: @Ron: imagine you encipher a file known to contain many long sequences of 00 bytes (as many files found in practice do). These long sequences of 00 bytes in the plaintext will degenerate into blocks of size `key.Length` that are identical in the ciphertext. These blocks of ciphertext have, precisely, the value of `key[]`.

Comment: Yes, the long identical sequences will definitely degenerate into blocks of key.length. BUT, if upon reaching the end of the key I use that key to get a new SHA512 hash, then this will be obviated. I tested it out and that is what happened. Doesn't solve all the problems. The user's initialization vector for the key is not limited to Ascii characters (i.e., printable chars from 0x20 to 0x7F). The plaintext could be anything, an executable, or text file. I add all this to see if creating a new key will fix that issue. I used a file of mostly 0x00 to test.

Comment: @Ron Vulnerable against known plaintext. Stop now and use a stream cipher. Your code can be broken by anybody that has followed an intro course into crypto (e.g. the one by Dan Boneh). This comment may contain product placement.

Comment: @Ron If you want to use SHA512 as stream cipher, use it an an existing mode, like CTR. CFB and OFB work as well, as long as you pass in the key on each iteration and not just in the beginning. But I'd rather use a dedicated stream cipher like Salsa20.

Comment: @Ron Blocks of plaintext can be brute forced based on linguistical patterns, or guessed at based on regular formats like email and HTTP headers, or human habits like regular reports, greetings and salutations. For example, if I know you've encrypted an executable I can guess at certain strings and libraries included in the executable and use them as a crib. [Guessing at the plaintext is one of the cribs used to break Enigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) making this attack *literally older than computers*.

Comment: I've never seen the term "crip" used in any serious cryptanalytic publication. Mostly, because it is such a imprecise expression. It is much better to talk about frequency analysis (uni-, bi, trigrams), frequently used (or expected) words and phrases (like in the enigma attacks), which is a form of  known plaintext attack (with high probability).