# Signal's Key Wrap: is it safe and is it custom?

Tags: hmac, signal-protocol, key-wrap, siv

The iOS version of Signal application (not the protocol) [includes a form of key wrap](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Pods/blob/main/SignalCoreKit/SignalCoreKit/src/Cryptography.swift#L64-L90) that I've never seen elsewhere: SHA256-HMAC-SIV.

It's used to encrypt your master key with your `pwHash(PIN)` before sending it to signal.org's Key Backup Service.

So far as I can tell, it does the following:

```
SHA256-HMAC-SIV(kek, raw)
kek: key encryption key
raw: original master key bytes

key_auth = HMAC(kek, "auth")
key_enc  = HMAC(kek, "enc")
iv       = Truncate(HMAC(key_auth, raw), 16 bytes)
key_xor  = HMAC(iv, key_enc)

output   = key_xor ^ raw
```

It derives 2 subkeys, for auth & encryption, like many approaches do. Then it creates a truncated MAC over the raw key for the deterministic IV.

But then it uses the IV as an HMAC key, and the encryption key as the HMAC message to produce a single "block" that they XOR with the raw key.

It seems very clever, but what's the right way to reason about the security overall?

Comment: Are you asking why a stream cipher based on HMAC can be considered secure?

Comment: Yeah, that’s essentially what it is, right? (Wouldn’t have found the words for it without your comment, but it seems obvious now…) It seems fine, but I’m not a cryptographer so I don’t know the model that would be used to show it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is.

After the [comment by forest](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/103724/signals-key-wrap-is-it-safe-and-is-it-custom?noredirect=1#comment224115_103724), I found this other question about building a stream cipher from HMAC in CTR mode. One answer gives a detailed explanation of using any one-way hash function as a stream cipher. Another answer gives quotes from *Applied Cryptography* about using such a cipher in CFB mode.

See the full discussion here:

[Can I use HMAC-SHA1 in counter mode to make a stream cipher?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/can-i-use-hmac-sha1-in-counter-mode-to-make-a-stream-cipher)