# How to crack sha256 used as streamcipher with known or guessable block

Tags: hash, block-cipher, sha-256, stream-cipher, blocksize

Using SHA-256 as a stream cipher appears to bear cryptographic weaknesses, however, I am not quite sure how to implement them in decryption.

Assume that I have an encryption function using 64-byte blocks.
I encrypt each of the blocks with the hash of the previous to produce my ciphertext.
The weak link here is, that I know, or can guess the very first block of bytes.

In one of the posts linked below, I read:

> I should mention that if there is any full block of known or guessable plaintext in your message, your scheme is easily broken because given pad(i) anyone can compute pad(i+1). So guess one block of plaintext, XOR it against the ciphertext to recover a possible pad value, then compute the next pad value and see if the recovered ciphertext in that block seems valid.

Can anyone elaborate on what exactly is meant here? If I know the first block, do I xor it against the hashed first block? If so how does that help me crack the next hashes that are H(prevHashedBlock + currentPlaintextBlock)?

I am aware this has to do with hashing states and such but I haven't found much on the web.

I have read the following posts:
[Is it feasible to build a stream cipher from a cryptographic hash function?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-it-feasible-to-build-a-stream-cipher-from-a-cryptographic-hash-function)
[Is SHA-256 secure as a CTR block cipher?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1656/is-sha-256-secure-as-a-ctr-block-cipher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such weakness if SHA-256 is used in CTR mode. ChaCha20 is already one built in this way.

You are using SHA-256 in a chaining way to output a stream to encrypt the message with x-or;

\begin{align}
O_1 & = H(key) \oplus H(message)\\
O_i & = H(O_{i-1})
\end{align}

Then the encryption is executed with x-oring $O_i$s.

$$C_i = P_i \oplus O_i$$

Now assume that you have a known-plaintext for some block $j$. This means that you get $O_j$

$$O_j =  P_j \oplus C_j$$

Now use the stream producing equation

\begin{align}
O_{j+1} &= H(O_j)\\
O_{j+2} &= H(O_{j+1})\\
   \vdots  \quad   & \quad\quad\vdots \\
O_{j+t} &= H(O_{j+t-1})\\
   \vdots  \quad   & \quad\quad\vdots \\
\end{align}

As you can see, you get the rest of the stream output from the position $j$. If you have the first position then you will get all.

This is the weakness of such a scheme on the other hand the CTR mode is designed for PRFs and it is common to initialize it with some good hash functions.

---

See with an image

[image]

As one can see, if you get any of the output $O_j$ then you can get the rest due to the hash chaining.

Comment: So XORing Oj with Cj should yield the plaintext of block j? Thanks for the image, it helped me understand your explanation better.

Comment: Furthermore, what exactly is Oj? Because it obviously isn't the finshed hash, correct? Because H(key+ptxt) = C1 not O1; so when decrypting this in a program, how would I yield O1?

Comment: That is why I draw it. Sometimes an image can tell a thousand words. $O_j$'s are the output of the hash function. When decrypting just x-or the ciphertext with $O_j$'s like in the One-time-Pad.

Comment: The first hash needs to be $hash(key)\oplus hash(ptxt)$, which doesn't change the attack, I'll correct it later...